# how to not save extra records if they are nil using x.times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `x.times` to build a nested form fields to save multiple records in the database.

What I want to do is, if the user doesn't type anything in one of the, let say, 2 fields `2.times` then it will only save the one that is filled.

Here's the controller

```
class Dashboard::ComplaintsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @complaint = Complaint.new
    2.times { @complaint.witnesses.build }
  end

  def create
    @complaint = current_user.complaints.build(complaint_params)
    if @complaint.save
      redirect_to dashboard_complaint_path(@complaint)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

and here's the view

```
<%= form_for @complaint, url: {action: 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Ej: Trabajo realizado incorrectamente', class: 'form-control', tabindex: '-1' %>
  <%= f.fields_for :witnesses do |witnesses_form| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
        <%= witnesses_form.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Escriba el nombre del testigo', tabindex: '-1' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
        <%= witnesses_form.text_field :phone, placeholder: 'Escriba el número de teléfono' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Sorry if it seems like a noob question, but I haven't had much experience with rubyonrails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to fix this by adding in the model the following:

I had this only in my complaints model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :witnesses
```

I changed it to this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :witnesses, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }
```

Now it only saves if they have input a witness name in this case.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html